# Materialize - Collapsible List - Radio Buttons Don't Work

Tags: forms, radio-button, materialize

I'm building a brief form with Materialize and i'm looking to keep the sections within the Collapsible list feature however within one of the sections i need to use radio buttons, but they don't seem to be working within the code i've got set up. I've included a pen to view the code of an excerpt that I have within the body.

https://codepen.io/RPMcwilliams/pen/EvOqRm

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body style="height:10000px">
    <h1>Example Form</h1>

    <div class="row" name="Accordian">
      <div class="input-field col s8">
          <ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="accordion">
              <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons"></i>Example</div>
                  <div class="collapsible-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <form action="#">
                          <p>
                            <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="one"/>
                            <label for="one">one</label>
                            <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="two"/>
                            <label for="two">two</label>
                            <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="three"/>
                            <label for="three">three</label>
                            <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="four"/>
                            <label for="four">four</label>
                          </p>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```